# Post Async Request with JSON body in c# not working

Tags: c#, json, post, httpclient

I'm trying to do a POST request with some simple JSON body in c#. I'm using HttpClient to do the request. I'm tryin the following:

```
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", cred.Access_token);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{'filter' : {'updated_since' : '2020-12-05T13:11:19+00:00'}}");

        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("invoices.list", data).ConfigureAwait(false);

        ...
    }
```

I add a simple filter in the JSON string, but as a result the filter is not working, I get all the results. When I try the same in Postman, everything is working fine. So I think there is some problems in the JSON string.

JSON in Postman:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "updated_since": "2020-12-05T13:11:19+00:00"
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: `json` isn't what you think it is. Largely because you aren't serialising an _object_. You are serialising a _string_.

Comment: I suspect what you meant to do was something like: `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { filter = new { updated_since = "2020-12-05T13:11:19+00:00" }});`

Comment: @mjwills, Thank you! I indeed forgot to Serialize the string. It is working now like i want it. Thank you.

Comment: `I indeed forgot to Serialize the string.` Well, it is more that you serialised it _twice_ - but awesome that you got it working.

Comment: you didn't need to use serialization at all since the string you had was actually valid JSON it could be passed directly.

Comment: @Claies, Ok, Thank you for your input. Is the one method better of the other? Or is it a choice by the developer ?

Comment: well, if you are hardcoding the JSON in as a string, it doesn't make sense to serialize it, especially if it's data that never changes.  but if you are creating the JSON from objects fetched from some other functions, then it's much more likely that you want to Serialize the Object, rather than try to parse the object out property by property to create the JSON by hand.  I would assume that you only used this JSON string in your example as a placeholder and are going to actually update the date dynamically, so this was just more of an observation on the fact that you already had valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I indeed used the example as a placeholer, the date is being updated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Like @mjwills said in the comment, I did not `Serialize` an object, but a string.

I changed

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{'filter' : {'updated_since' : '2020-12-05T13:11:19+00:00'}}");
```

to

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { filter = new { updated_since = "2020-12-05T13:11:19+00:00" }});
```

And everything is working now.